# getting the details from a previous date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that tracks assets, at different point but I need to find out when the asset comes in to point 4 I need to know when it was last seen at point 1.

I have tried to get the max date for when the asset is at point 1 and the date is < than the date at point 4 but to no avail.

```
with CTE as 
( select distinct TAG, UID_KEG, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Movement_date,105) as 
Inbound, L.CAPTION 
from MOVEMENT M1
inner join KEG K on M1.UID_KEG = K.UNIQUE_ID
inner join STATION S on M1.UID_STATION = S.UNIQUE_ID
Inner join LOCATION L on S.UID_LOCATION = L.UNIQUE_ID
where DATEPART(year,movement_date) = '2019'
and DATEPART(Month,MOVEMENT_DATE) = '07'
and UID_MOVEMENT_TYPE = 4
)
select CTE.TAG, CTE.Inbound, 
MAX(Convert(VARCHAR(10),M2.MOVEMENT_DATE,105)) as 'Last Seen'
from MOVEMENT M2
Inner join CTE on M2.UID_KEG = CTE.UID_KEG
inner join KEG K2 on M2.UID_KEG = K2.UNIQUE_ID
inner join STATION S2 on M2.UID_STATION = S2.UNIQUE_ID
Inner join LOCATION L2 on S2.UID_LOCATION = L2.UNIQUE_ID
where UID_MOVEMENT_TYPE = 1
and   Convert(VARCHAR(10),M2.MOVEMENT_DATE,105) < Inbound
group by CTE.TAG, CTE.Inbound
```

What I would Ideally want is a list of asset tags, the date at point 4 and then the date at point 1 which I can then link to other tables and gather some more information.

```
TAGID, Point 4, Point 1
1234, 06/07/2019, 10/03/2019
45678, 5/04/2019, 01/12/2018
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the [`first_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data with your expected output?

Comment: Break it down. Write the expression you need before digesting that massive wall of SQL.

Comment: I think Its the massive wall of SQL thats the issue. I'm not sure the query is right. I know what the where clause needs to be it's how I pull out the date the asset was seen at point 1 that's the issue.